# Sample list evenly

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list with 30000 plus elements. I'd like to sample 500 points from that list in an even manner, into another list.

More, ideally I'd like to compress the 30000 into a 500 long list by averaging in 30000/500=60 points at a time. I.e. an element of the end list is a `Mean[]` of 60 elements on the first list.

I can construct an expressions to do both options, but I'd like to know if Mathematica has something in stock.
This is hugely useful for signal processing, hence my expectation regarding Mathematica's functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's generate a random list of reals:

```
list = RandomReal[{-100, 100}, 30000];
```

There is `Mean` which can do what you expect. i.e. every consecutive 60 elements is averaged:

```
Partition[ list, 500] // Transpose // Mean
```

Comment: I knew it. There is something hugely useful in Mathematica for this.

Comment: And if I want only the last element I can easily take the last element of all partitions with `Partition[list, 500][[All,500]]`.

Comment: The above is the most straightforward approach, in case of expecting something more involved one should first mention about known methods in the OP, however I believe there is no need for complicating life.

Comment: @A.Vieira Instead of `Partition[list, 500][[All,500]]` you can also write `Partition[list, 500][[All,-1]]` or even `Last /@ Partition[list,500]` to get the last element of each partition.

Answer (score 5):

```
SeedRandom[1]
list = RandomReal[{-100, 100}, 30000]; 

Developer`PartitionMap[Mean, list, 500]
```

> {-1.55803,2.22818,-0.0508766,3.25136,0.846088,1.94176,-1.73064,1.07554,0.247383,6.93271,2.76486,0.966219,-2.52573,1.78763,-4.1424,-1.30308,0.350464,0.447681,2.12322,-1.69277,1.47585,-0.923214,2.44039,2.92054,1.9305,-1.65154,-1.5551,-2.78769,2.63487,0.458904,3.18371,0.00747208,-1.99041,-3.63672,-4.10655,2.16469,2.63422,0.609351,0.73959,1.46082,-1.55098,-2.46442,-1.34251,-6.38555,3.16249,0.381931,-0.262874,-0.575258,0.745162,-4.29312,-0.168863,-0.275357,-4.23135,1.23062,2.6862,4.61055,2.48747,2.65438,-4.45548,1.09867}

Gives the same result as artes's answer:

```
% == (Partition[list, 500] // Transpose // Mean)
```

> True

Re: ***if I want only the last element I can easily take the last element of all partitions with...***, you can also use `` Developer`PartitionMap `` with `Last` replacing `Mean`:

```
Developer`PartitionMap[Last, list, 500]
```

> {-15.2243, -53.5129, -59.1726, -89.9014, -21.8066, 94.7291, -50.4855, -40.2763,26.8482, -37.5492, -39.7777, 36.555, -35.0392, 69.7234, -47.4006,12.0806, -54.2981, -5.91096, 51.94,11.6728, -39.7397, 61.1442, -11.5572, 44.7992, 55.2541, -12.8397, 76.2317, 72.2243, -46.5035, 3.4014, -99.478, -67.626, 24.6064, 38.3583, 42.6547, 15.6142, 25.748, -90.9753, 97.2486, 66.1974, -61.1141, -78.6101, -60.4224, -53.2592, 42.5433, 8.88568, 33.5063, -99.2404, 97.9869, -5.56118, -67.6508, 92.2843, 40.1395, -18.5641, -93.7015, -40.7611, 85.1767, 82.3689, -89.0389, 18.9333}

Alternatively, you can use `Downsample`:

```
Downsample[list, 500, 500] == %
```

> True

Comment: Cool, didn't know about `PartitionMap`! (+1)

Answer (score 1):

Since Version 10.2 there is

```
BlockMap[Mean, list, 500];
```